# Filter or map in jinja2

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, jinja2

I'm trying to filter or map this yml file. Up to now I was able to access it with this

```
{{services[0].version}}
```

But I need to access it with it name, without the position.

Yml file

```
"services":
  - "service": "front"
    "image": "acalls-caselog-web-app"
    "version": "latest" 
  - "service": "back"
    "image": "acalls-caselog-web-service"
    "version": "latest"
```

docker-compose.yml.j2

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  front:
    image: url/{{services[0].image}}:{{services[0].version}}
    ports: 
      - "81:81"
    extra_hosts:
      - "backend:172.32.3.46" 
    environment:
      profile: preproduction
   back:
    image: url/ {{services[1].image}} : {{services[1].version}}
    ports: 
      - "82:82"
    extra_hosts:
      - "backend:172.32.3.46" 
    environment:
      profile: preproduction
```

I really don't now If I need to use map, filter or there is another form like service.service(front).image

Comment: The position is required. As written in your previous question, with a template, you can add a loop index counter, then write an if statement against a specific `services[i].name == "front"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844876/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) filter:

```
{{services | selectattr("service", "equalto", "front")}}
```

In your YAML, you can apply it like this:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  front:
    image: {% with front=services|selectattr("service", "equalto", "front") -%}
      url/{{front.image}}:{{front.version}}
    {%- endwith %}
    ports: 
      - "81:81"
    extra_hosts:
      - "backend:172.32.3.46" 
    environment:
      profile: preproduction
   back:
    image: {% with back = services|selectattr("service", "equalto", "back") -%}
      url/ {{back.image}} : {{back.version}}
    {%- endwith %}
    ports: 
      - "82:82"
    extra_hosts:
      - "backend:172.32.3.46" 
    environment:
      profile: preproduction
```